# Update a view from within a thread inside getView?

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have an activity class that calls my custom adapter class which extends a base adapter. Inside my `getView` method I have a `button.setOnClickListener` within which there is a thread which downloads data. I want to set the button text to "downloading" when the user clicks, then after the download is finished, set the button text to "finished". How can I do this?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
//some code here
private void setAdapter(ArrayList arrayList) {      
    listView.setAdapter(new UserAdapter(context,arrayList));        
}
}


public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
     Holder holder = new Holder();      
     holder.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
     holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try{
                  //set button text to "downloading"
                  //establish an http connection and download data
                  //after download done, if successfull set button text to downloaded
                  //if download failed, set button text to failed.
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                }
            }
            }
        ).start();
      }
    });

    return view;
}
private class Holder {
    private Button button;
}
}
```

Comment: You're going to have a hard time with this approach.  What if the button scrolls off the screen in the middle of a download, the view get recycled, then gets reused to a new row in your ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update a view fron inside the thread use runOnUithread inside the getView method like this. Inside the activity you can use directly but outside the activity you have to use the context.

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        //If there are stories, add them to the table

      try{
           }
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
        }
    }
});
```

For http request you can use asyncTask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm, except it needs a try inside the run which is missed :). Also it needed a cast to Activity.